# Passing function does not evaluate

Tags: javascript, function

Please consider this javascript:

```
var a = function(arg1) {
    alert(arg1);
}

a("hello");

a(function() { return "world"; });
```

How do I get it to return "world" in the second call? Right now it returns the whole function as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just execute the function expression, it will return `world` and that will be passed to the `a` function

```
a((function() { return "world"; })());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/h2z6R/)

Comment: While the other answers are correct, this one hits the nail smack into the wall.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function, not just refer to it:

```
alert(arg1());
```

If you need to cope with `a` being called with either a string or a function, you'll need to check the type of the argument with `typeof` and handle them differently.

Answer (score 1):

With the second call `arg1` is a function.

To get the result you have to execute the function:

```
alert(arg1());
```